# Stop object from receiving shadow

Tags: materials, lighting, shadows, shader-nodes

I know I can stop an object from casting a shadow under "Ray Visibility," but can I also stop an object from receiving one in Cycles? Sometimes I want an object to cast a shadow, but only specific things should be kept out of the shadow. The Light Path node has the output "Is shadow ray," but it doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't write in all caps in the title or body of any posts, it is the written equivalent of shouting, is [harder to read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Readability) and may be [considered rude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Computing). Please use the [edit] button below the post to change you text into regular case.

Comment: I think what I might do is use view layers to isolate the objects from each other.

Comment: I had the same issue and i have solved it using the compositor + cryptomatte,
would be nice to have a checkbox button same as casting shadow has.